# Service Token for External API | Databricks

Tags: databricks, data-warehouse, delta-lake, aws-databricks, databricks-sql

I am currently experimenting with Databricks. I'd like to leverage the [Python SQL Connector](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html) to allow external APIs to access certain tables through Databricks.

Using the Python SQL Connector requires the use of a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html#generate-a-personal-access-token) to authenticate with Databricks.

The issue here is I do not want the access token for a service to be tied to my personal identity, ideally I'd like the access token to be attached to a service identity. Databricks only allows me to create users with a first name, last name, and email. Is creating a service identity even possible to externally access tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's really possible.  You need to create a service principal (via [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-sp.html) or [Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/service_principal)), add it to corresponding group that has access to data (via [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-sp.html#add-to-a-group), UI, or [Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/group_member)), give it permission to use personal access token (via [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/permissions.html#tag/Token-permissions) or [Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/permissions#token-usage)), and then generate a token for it (via [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/token-management.html#operation/create-obo-token) or [Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/obo_token)).